# how to update UIBarButtonItem badge in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I put badge in 'UINavigationBarButton'. when I come to home screen it show proper value. but when I go for that 'UINavigationBarButton' action I move to second viewcontroller. Here In viewcontroller I called API and that give me the count and in second viewcontroller I called API and that give also me value. In home viewcontroller I subtract both value and that value show into the badge. Now when I come back from second viewcontroller to home viewcontroller at that time badge count will be '0'. how this possible in ios swift ?

My HomeViewcontroller code is this

```
var bellButton : MIBadgeButton!
var bellButtonmage : UIImageView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var webcount = 0
    var notificationcount = 0

    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "webcount") != nil{
        webcount = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "webcount") as! Int
    }
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "oldcount") != nil{
        notificationcount = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "oldcount") as! Int
    }

   let remainCount = webcount - notificationcount

    self.countnotificationAPI()

    bellButton = MIBadgeButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-50, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    bellButton.badgeEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 5, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
    bellButtonmage = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 5, width: 20, height: 20))
    bellButtonmage.image = UIImage.init(named: "notification")
    bellButton.addSubview(bellButtonmage)

    bellButton.badgeString = String.init(format: "%d", remainCount)
    bellButton.badgeTextColor = UIColor.white
    bellButton.badgeBackgroundColor = UIColor.red

    let rightbarbutton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: bellButton)
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbarbutton
    self.bellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(notificationaction), for:.touchUpInside)
  }

 @objc func notificationaction() {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotonotification", sender: nil)
}

func countnotificationAPI()  {

   let param = ["API" : "notification_count"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

        if  let datastring = response.result.value  as? [String:Any] {
            let notificationcount = datastring["notification_count"] as! Int
            UserDefaults.standard.set(notificationcount, forKey: "webcount")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

           }
        }
      }
    }
```

In SecondViewcontroller code is

```
 func notificationAPI()  {

   let param = ["API" : "notification_list"]
     Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

        if  let datastring = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
            let notificationlist = datastring["notification_list"] as! [[String:Any]]
            let oldcount = datastring["notification_count"]

           UserDefaults.standard.set(oldcount, forKey: "oldcount")
           UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
               }
              }
            }
```

My navigationBarButton is placed in homeviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **viewDidLoad()**
try your code in

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //update badge count here
    }
```